# Separation of Spring logs and User - defined logs

Tags: java, spring, maven, logging, log4j

I am building a Spring boot project with Tomcat server where in Spring automatically takes care of all the logging mechanism, all the logs are present in "catalina.out" file.

Now that, I have a requirement where I need to log only specific information to a separate log file.

I have done the below configuration, but now all the logs including the main logs are appending in the same file.

I need only specific logs into a separate log file.

Can anyone suggest me a solution for this?

My pom.xml looks like this.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

My log4j.properties look like this.

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,file

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

#Redirect to Tomcat logs folder
#log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.home}/logs/logging.log

log4j.appender.file.File=/my_log.log
log4j.appender.file.Append=true
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

The java file looks like this.

```
static org.apache.log4j.Logger log4jLogger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());

log4jLogger.info("My specific logs here");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [FAQ Logging](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Logging#Q6), the `CATALINA_BASE/logs/catalina.out` contains the output of `System.out` and `System.err`.

Therefore, you need to redirect the output of Spring
to `System.out`. That can be done using [**`org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender`**](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/ConsoleAppender.html).

Using this appender, your configuration file may be similar:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=info, stdout

# Direct log messages to the console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/my_log.log
log4j.appender.file.Append=true
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Output to the file only from certain packages (e.g. your application)
log4j.logger.com.foo=trace, file
log4j.logger.org.company=trace, file
```

If you do not want that your application also log to `stdout` <sup>**1**</sup>, use:

```
# Output to the file only from certain packages (e.g. your application)
log4j.logger.com.foo=trace, file
log4j.additivity.com.foo=false
log4j.logger.org.company=trace, file
log4j.additivity.org.company=false
```

See more in [*Short introduction to log4j*](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) on [Apache log4j 1.2](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) webpage.

---

*Notes*

1. [*Log4j Tutorial: Additivity – what and why?*](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/08/log4j-tutorial-additivity-what-and-why/)

Comment: Paul, your suggestion solved to a certain stage where in I can see my Console output like before. But all the logs with "info" level are still getting appended in my specific log file which I dont need.

Comment: What configuration are you using? You could use http://pastie.org/ to share it and typing here the generated URL.

Comment: The instance of log4j must be `static Logger log4jLogger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);` What is the package of `MyClass`?

Comment: Package of MyClass is "com.foo.controller".
Although, all the Spring generated logs with "INFO" level are also getting appended in the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul. Its working now. But I want to know why it was not working as expected before?

Answer (score 0):

You should create multiple loggers that point to different files (now you have just one, that why all ends in one file). Then you can distinguish the loggers with some prefix to the package. Something like

```
log4j.logger.file1.com.spring.something=.../define the logger
log4j.logger.file2.com.spring.somethingelse=.../second logger
```

and then when obtaining the logger use something like

```
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("file1" + MyClass.class.getName());
```

Comment: Thanks Nadir. But how can I still maintain the original Spring logs in catalina.out?

Comment: If you want to use standard log just dont prefix the class name with "file1". Also remember to have a standard logger in that situation.

Comment: Thanks Nadir. As I have excluded "spring-boot-starter-logging", nothing is getting printed on my console.